# Not able to reinstall the kernel or to use the latest version

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

On a ubuntu server, I try to do "sudo modprob" and I have this error :

```
$ sudo depmod
[sudo] password for deployer:
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.8.0-38-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
```

**I tried to reinstall the kernel but I have this :**

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-3.8.0-38 linux-headers-3.8.0-38-generic linux-image-3.8.0-38-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.8.0-38
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-38'
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.8.0-38-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.8.0-38-generic'
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-3.8.0-38-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-3.8.0-38-generic'
```

**I tried to install a latest version like this :**

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.13.0-24 linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic
```

**But I always have this result :**

```
$ uname -r
3.8.0-38-generic
```

I don't know why it does not change.

Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Have you (after successful installation) rebooted the Linux? (Though, if you got installation errors and your installation failed you should have a look into that first.)

Comment: Yes I did. I finally found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I did not think it was important but I am a Digital Ocean's VPS. I followed [this solution](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-update-a-digitalocean-server-s-kernel). I had to change the kernel version in the control panel and reboot through the control panel.